# Is there an easy way to do this in OpenCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv

I want to translate this Matlab code into OpenCV:

```
img(mask == label) = val;
```

I did it in a dirty way (simply visit each pixel in mask and assign values). Is there any quick and neat way?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
img.setTo(val, mask==label);
```